# React functional component in nested maps rerender multiple times

Tags: reactjs, rerender

I have three components, App,Movies, and Input

In Movies, it display movie details and render input fields for each movie.

```
export default function Movies(props) {
  console.log("HOW MANY TIMES")
  return (
    <div className="movies">
    {props.movies && props.movies.map(m=> <section>
    <span>{m.name}</span>
    {m.actors.map(a=>(<div>
    <div>{a.name}</div>
    <div>{props.salaryChildren && React.cloneElement(props.salaryChildren, {id: m.id})}</div>
```

My app component renders Movies by Type

```
export default function App(props) {
  const library = [
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "A",
      type: "blockbuster",
      movies: [
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "Cast away",
          actors: [{ name: "Tom Hanks" }, { name: "Actor B" }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  const renderByType = (type) => {
    if (type === "blockbuster") {
      return <input />;
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      {library.map((l) => (
        <div>
          <Movies movies={l.movies} salaryChildren={renderByType(l.type)} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
    </div>))}
    </section>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Input

```
export default function Input(props) {
  
  return (<input/>)
}
```

When i console log how many time movies it was render inside handle change of the input, it display as many times as movies props I have. I want it to render once. not x times by movies.length

Any idea why it behaves in such way?

Comment: You are looping through the array using `map`. It would create as many components as the length of the array.

Comment: correct, however, inside input when I put console.log before return, i get it rendered n time the size of the array when setting the state, it supposed to only re-render once.

Comment: They are separate components with their own render cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop inside the App component, you can just provide a list of movies from the library because of the loop of the movies inside the Movies component.

```
return (
    <div>
       <Movies movies={library.movies} />
    </div>
);
```